# Partner Community user not able to convert lead and create record

Tags: trigger, community, partner

I encountering an error in CRM where user is not able to convert a lead or add any account. When I logged in on same account in IST its working and I am able to do same thing but when someone trying to create or convert record from US he is not able to create or convert record. he got trigger

> **error System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001**

. Don't understand why this error showing for location wised. Can any one have any idea, how to resolve this- Many thanks

Comment: There must be some trigger running. Could you investigate what are the triggers written on Lead and Opportunity.

Comment: It might be trigger issue wherein for a particular User the SOQL query is retrieving too many query rows for that transaction.

Comment: Hi @Ashwani;@RCS  Trigger written on Account, But the problem is coming for specific timezone, I am able to create record and convert Lead by login same credential but when my sales guy try to convert lead or create Account from US he is getting this error. if this error caused by trigger so how I am able to create same thing with same credential??

Comment: @GauravDPathak Can you check log while converting lead

Comment: @Reshma Yes!! And everything working fine because I am able to create record but when my sales guys creating record from different location(US), he get the same error which i mention on my qus -- many thanks for your response